# PrimeNG DataTable programmatically select row checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Hi I will be having a 'selectedrow' array list in my ngOninit(). I want to make selection to all row checkboxes which is in 'selectedrow' variable.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4vvqp4-xbrzdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

you want to push some card in to `selectedCars`.

but `selectedCars` is not a list, because of that you see ERROR: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

to fix it just make `selectedCars` as list (with default value)

```
selectedCars:any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the selectedCars as type `any` but you are not assigning it as empty array,so initially the value of `selectedCars` gets undefined that's why the default selected item is not binding to the table. change the code like this

```
selectedCars:any[] = [];
```

Comment: Hi Siva, I have updated that code but still it not highlighting the row or checkbox selection is not coming.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4vvqp4-4cggas?file=src/app/app.component.ts